# Laravel4+Bootstrap: How to make fields red on validation error

Tags: php, validation, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Inside a Laravel4 + Bootstrap 2.3.1 I have a form properly working with validation.
There are three fields obligatory: Name - Email - Phone.

When nothing is inserted, or the email is not in a proper format, the error messages are displayed.
But besides this, I would like to make the fields red, to show better where the error is.
How can I do this in Laravel + Bootstrap?

This is the form with the three fields obligatory:

```
<form name="room" method="post"  class="narrow_width">

 <label><span><i class="icon-user"></i></span> Name <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
  {{ Form::text('name',Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'span7 border-radius-none')) }}

  <label><span><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i></span> Email <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
  {{ Form::text('email',Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'span7 border-radius-none')) }}

  <label><span><i class="icon-phone"></i></span> Phone number <span class="color-red">*</span></label>          
  {{ Form::text('phone',Input::old('phone'), array('class' => 'span7 border-radius-none')) }}  

  <p><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-u">Send Message</button></p>
 </form>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You really should check out Former - its amazing - and it handles all of this automatically: https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this with the laravel Form class. I personally use my own package https://github.com/AndreasHeiberg/theme for this. You can use it if you wan't but it's subject to change.

Anyway raw code to do this is the following:

```
<div class="control-group {{ $errors->has($id) ? 'error' : false }}">
    <label for="{{ $id }}" class="control-label">{{ $text }} {{ $required ? '<span class="required-red">*</span>' : ''}}</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="{{ $type }}" id="{{ $id }}" name="{{ $id }}" value="{{ $value }}">
        @if ($helpText)
            <span class='help-inline'>{{ $helpText }}</span>
        @endif
        @foreach($errors->get($id) as $message)
            <span class='help-inline'>{{ $message }}</span>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

This being the important part

```
<div class="control-group {{ $errors->has($id) ? 'error' : false }}">
```

You can wrap this up in a form macro http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros use a helper function or my package to do this.

With my package you would just use:

```
+@formText('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use Form macros, there is a bunch available here for Bootstrap 3:

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11960

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts, especially @AndHeiberg.
For reason of simplicity, i decide to renounce to Laravel-Bootstrap validation and use instead a jquery plugin: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

The main reason is that is extremely easy to use.
It's enough to call the plugin and insert 'required' into the tag.
And the plugin will do all the rest, highlighting the field in red and displaying an error message for that field.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to make the error more obvious to where it is, you can wrap the message text that is returned from Laravel validation errors in a span and give styling to that.

```
{{ $errors->first('email', "<span class='error'>:message</span>")}}
```

where `:message` is a "placeholder" for your error message. And then you can give any styling to `.error` spans as you wish. Check this [Laracast lesson](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/12) for more details (after 3:10).

Comment: I'm doing something similar but it always html decodes the `<` and `"` instead of outputting the actual character i want (ie it'll show `&lt;` and `&quot;` instead). Laravel 4.1 here

Comment: I tried this on Laravel 5.0, and doesn't seem like it works. The `<span>..</span` is printed as an actual string.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage this answer is valid for Laravel 4.2, I'm not sure if it would work with 5.0 as I haven't used it.

Comment: It might be useful to some so... `{{ $string }}` will html escape your string ending with things like &gt;. To stop Laravel from escaping your html, use `{!! $string !!}`

Answer (score -1):

In bootstrap, you can create errorfield with the id "inputError":

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
```

Comment: I don't know if this was the official recommended way of doing this in a very old version of Bootstrap, but you're only allowed to use an ID once per document in HTML, so this would render your document invalid if you had more than one error.